# When is the product of regular matrices regular

Tags: gr.group-theory, linear-algebra, matrices, finite-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator{\GL}{\operatorname{GL}}$We say that a matrix $g \in \GL_n(F)$ is regular if it has a centraliser of minimal dimension, or equivalently, if the minimal and characteristic polynomials of $g$ are equal.

Regular elements are well studied in groups of Lie type: for example "most" elements of a given Lie type group $G$ are regular. Furthermore, if $G$ is non-abelian finite simple, it is conjectured by J. Thompson that there exists a class $C \subset G$ such that $C^2=G$ — the best candidates for such a $C$ are regular semisimple.

**So my question:**
Given regular $g_1,g_2 \in \GL_n(F)$, is there any criterion for deducing that the product $g_1g_2$ is also regular?

Given the conjecture of Thompson (ignoring that $\GL_n$ is not simple for the moment), it would seem that information concerning the Jordan normal form of $g_i$ will not be sufficient.

Thanks.

//
**EDIT:** I'm interested in arbitrary fields, but particularly when $F$ is algebraically closed.

Comment: I do want $g_1$ and $g_2$ to be regular, and I've edited the question appropriately -- thanks for spotting.

Comment: From your reference to Jordan Normal Form, I'm guessing that we should assume the field is algebraically closed? Or are you also interested in this question for matrices over finite fields?

Comment: In the case when $g_1$ and $g_2$ commute, $g_2$ is a polynomial in $g_1$ and so $g_1g_2$ is also a polynomial in $g_1$. For algebraically closed fields, I think the question then reduces to: if $X$ is a $d \times d$ nilpotent Jordan block, when is $Xf(X)$ cyclic? Answer: if and only if $f(0) \not=0$. (This reduction clearly needs some work, e.g. it has to apply to the case when $g_1 = g_2^{-1}$.)